# Something wrong in "Character Count Java Program"

Tags: java, loops, count, character

This program is supposed to count the number of characters entered by a user. Where other is other characters such as !, @, $, etc. It is not supposed to count #. The following is my code to do this:

```
public class countchars {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        char sym;
        int up = 0;
        int low = 0;
        int digit = 0;
        int other = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter a character # to quit: ");
        sym = input.next().charAt(0);

        while (sym != '#') {
            System.out.print("Enter a character # to quit: ");

            if (sym >= 'a' && sym <= 'z') {
                low++;
            }
            if (sym >= 'A' && sym <= 'Z') {
                up++;
            }
            if (sym >= '0' && sym <= '9') {
                digit++;
            }
            if (sym >= '!' && sym <= '=') {
                other++;
            }

            sym = input.next().charAt(0);

        }

        System.out.printf("Number of lowercase letters: %d\n", low);
        System.out.printf("Number of uppercase letters: %d\n", up);
        System.out.printf("Number of digits: %d\n", digit);
        System.out.printf("Number of other characters: %d\n", other);
    }
}
```

The problem is with the "other" counter. If I entered !, @, and $, it will only count 2 of the 3 characters entered. What's the wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
        if (sym >= 'a' && sym <= 'z') {
            low++;
        } else if (sym >= 'A' && sym <= 'Z') {
            up++;
        } else if (sym >= '0' && sym <= '9') {
            digit++;
        } else {
            other++;
        }
```

or instead of else you can select the short set of what that character can be:

```
        } else if ("%!$&".contains(sym)){
            other++;
        }
```

Comment: to add an explanation: the special symbols may be excluded from the ascii range of "!" and "="

Answer (score 3):

if you take a look at the [ascii](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=ascii%20table) table, you'll see that:
'!' = 33
'=' = 61
'@' = 64

the '@' character isn't in the range you specified so it's not counted, replace the last condition with:

```
if (sym >= '!' && sym <= '@') {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
else {
    other++;
}
```

instead of

```
if (sym >= '!' && sym <= '=') {
    other++;
}
```

`#` will not be counted as `other` because you already filter it in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR(||) in condition instead of AND(&&)

```
if (sym == '!' || sym == '=' || sym == '@' || ...){
        other++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you catch "everything else"; you just use an `else` clause. That way you don't miss things, like you're doing now (because `'@'` isn't in the range you're checking). You want this:

```
else {
    other++;
}
```

where you currently have this:

```
if (sym >= '!' && sym <= '=') {
    other++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare char based on the ASCII value.
@ ASCII is 64
! ASCII is 33
= ASCII is 61

So @ isn't between "!" and "=" and doesn't increment your counter.

Answer (score 0):

Look here, and hopefully the answer will present it self!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

and are you sure the sequence $,5,$ will give you the right answer ? ;)